# How to add CSS in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, css, uiactionsheet

I'm designing `UIActionSheet` of Objective C and I want to add some more colors to `Actionsheet` buttons. Is it possible to Add through CSS styles ? If So please give me a example how to add styles to `UIButton`?

Comment: CSS will not work, the UI in iOS is not based on HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use CSS, give it a try using http://www.nativecss.com/ *(BTW, I am not endorsing the use of this site)*

Answer (score 0):

You can only use inline CSS in webview for HTML webPages. there is no way by which you can add CSS into native Controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for(UIView *view in actionSheet.subViews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
            //here you style your button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where to ADD CSS in this one .its irrelevant

Comment: I think enough people here wrote that you can't do css with native controls. I only suggested an alternative how to style buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways that you could actually achieve this:

- Using [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/)
- Using [NUI from Tom Benner](https://github.com/tombenner/nui)

They come with their own documentations, so you would have to review that in order to understand how to use the tools.

There's also another project on github, the name of which I currently forget, that allows you to use JSON markup too.